# How do I add cli arguments to py.test?

Tags: python, selenium, saucelabs

Im trying to have interchangeable config files and I'm using py.test to send the testing suite to the cloud.

The following works when I run them locally using `python main.py --site site1` in the terminal.

I'm trying to figure out how I can add cli arguments so that it will work with py.test

I have 3 files. main, config, and site1_config

main.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='CLI tests for an environment')
parser.add_argument('--site', nargs='?', help='the site to use for the config')
parser.add_argument('unittest_args', nargs='*')
#Get our property
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.site:
    config.localizeConfig(args.site)
sys.argv[1:] = args.unittest_args

unittest.main(verbosity = 2)
```

config.py

```
def localizeConfig(site):
    localizedConfig = __import__(site+'_config');
    # localizedConfig = __import__(site);
    #print dir(localizedConfig)
    props = filter(lambda a: not a.startswith('__'), dir(localizedConfig))
    #Iterate over each property and set it on the config
    for prop in props:
        if prop != 'os' and prop != 'sys' and prop != 'webdriver':
            globals()[prop] = getattr(localizedConfig, prop)
host_url = www.google.com
```

site1_config.py

```
host_url = www.yahoo.com
```

Im trying to set a flag so that when `py.test -n6 --boxed main.py site1` 
is run, the site1_config.py will copy over its contents into config.py

I'm not sure how I can get this to work with py.test

usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments:

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what you are trying to do, but in order to add CLI arguments to py.test check:
http://pytest.org/latest/example/simple.html:

```
# content of conftest.py 
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--cmdopt", action="store", default="type1",
        help="my option: type1 or type2")
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of your `unittest.main(verbosity = 2)` is `pytest.main(['-v'])`

Things to note:

- In pytest, I'm not sure verbosity level is selectable
- Some of the references on `pytest.main(input)` don't specify that the input has to be a list, but as of today it must be.

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html